# How can I fetch data from a php site (backend) in android?

Tags: php, android, json, jsoup, android-xml

Let's say there are 5 images,their headings and their description. How can I fetch the contents of one block (heading,image and description) and show in xml?

Comment: `show in xml` ?? How would that look like?

Comment: get the json data from the server and parse it and set it in the xml view

Comment: I need to make the image an imagebutton and then display the description in an xml file by using that button.Thanks in advance.